# How do I denote that something can be equal to either of two things.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I want a compact way of saying that $r$ can be either $a_i$ or $v$.

Is it correct to write
$$ r\in\{a_i, v\}$$
or rather, in an unsettling way,
$$r = a_i \lor v$$

Regards.

> Blockquote

Comment: Yes to the first; no to the second. More common is just to say “$r=a_i$ or $r=v$”, though.

Comment: Your first expression (set membership) is fine.  For the second one, normally you'd say $r=a_i \vee r=v$ instead.

Comment: The first one is correct, if you write the index set.

Comment: My only objection to the first one could be a misleading interpretation as
$$r\in\{a_i, v\} = \{r, a_i, v\}$$
I do not know if that happens, but certainly wouldn't like it to be the case.

Comment: If someone is misreading the first one that way, they’ve got some serious issues understanding mathematical notation.

Comment: And you would be right. Thank you all.

Comment: I think the teaching in our high schools leads students to think that it’s not truly mathematical unless it’s all in symbols, without words. Nothing could be farther from the truth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most correct way would be
$$r=a_i\lor r=v$$
I was coached to do this in secondary school – $r=a_i\lor v$ was deemed inadequate.

Comment: This answer would be improved if you explained why most mathematicians would say that $r=a_i\lor v$ is inadequate/inappropriate. "I was coached to do this in secondary school" could make it sound like there's no reason for doing it your first way rather than your second way.

It would also be nice if you explained why your first way is preferable to the set notation.